# android simulation 5.0.1(API 21) issue

Tags: android

I'm not able to run an android hybrid app on the emulator. The emulator is really slow and it gerentating this error:

```
[2015-10-12 00:17:12 - TestAppProjectTestAppAndroid] Failed to install TestAppProjectTestAppAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
 [2015-10-12 00:17:12 - TestAppProjectTestAppAndroid] (null)
[2015-10-12 00:17:13 - TestAppProjectTestAppAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

Can i have some solution on how to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need Virtual device just use Genymotion that work perfect and so fast
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download